# How to get the number of files in a directory in beego

Tags: go, beego

I'm new to go and am trying to make a script in go (beego) to get the count of files in a given directory

Comment: Are you having trouble getting the number of  files in a directory on the server, or sending an integer from the server to the client? Because those are two completely separate and unrelated questions.

Comment: I'm trying to get the number of files in a directory on the server, that's my main priority